# Dapper TypeHandler<string[]> breaks where condition

Tags: mysql, .net, dapper

i have a MySQL database connection with Dapper and i'm using a TypeHandler to parse a db string as a string[].

Problem is that TypeHandler requires to override both Parse and SetValue and i need to write a query that uses the statement IN (...) in the where condition, like in the example here:

```
using (var db = ADA_BaseDBManager.CreateADA_BaseDBConnectionDapper())
                {
                    SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new StringArrayHandler());

                    var superOdps = new string[]{"0200258416_70","0200258438_20","0200258649_10","0100942638_30","0200258768_10"};

                    var sql = "select * from odps_v2 ov where ov.ID_SuperODP in @superOdps";

                    var data = db.Query<DTOODP>(sql, new { superOdps});

return data;
                }
```

```
 public class StringArrayHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<string[]>
    {
        public override string[] Parse(object value)
        {
            if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return Utils.SerializedToArray(value.ToString());
        }

        public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, string[] value)
        {
            parameter.Value = $"('{Utils.ArrayToSerialized(value, "','")}')";
        }
    }
```

when i execute this code i have this exception:
`{"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(\\'0200258416_70\\',\\'0200258438_20\\',\\'0200258649_10\\',\\'0100942638_30\\',\\'0200' at line 1"}`

i tried changing the SetValue method to format a string that could be correct for mysql but the exception still came.

The only thing that actually worked is to convert the param array to a List() but that could be dangerous if someone forget to cast the object everytime.

Comment: Try var data = db.Query<DTOODP>(sql, new { superOdps = param });
The variable is substituted by the name.

Comment: Dapper does all this automatically anyway if you give it an `IEnumerable` of something, are you sure you actually need a manual mapper? https://www.learndapper.com/parameters#dapper-where-in-parameters

Comment: @PalleDue sorry, there was an error in the code i copied and i edited now. The error still persist btw (in vs my code was actually correct)

Comment: @Charlieface i need the manual mapper because of the DTOODP class which have some string[] parameters and other types. Everything works nicely in the where condition if i don't use the handler